# Is there a neater way of using `Include` in Linq-EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-database-first

For example:

```
 var emp = db.Employees
           .Include("CostCenter")
           .Single(e => e.Id == 123);
```

I do not like the idea of using magic strings to include navigation properties in my query, is there a more neat way of doing this? I am asking this because recently I changed a navigation property's name and I had to change this manually, it is just doesn't look nice.

Comment: You can create an extension to do the .include using reflection to get the name of the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can try to use lambda expressions. 
First of all include appropriate extensions in your project:

```
System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions
```

Then add appropriate namespace:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Now you can start using this:

```
var emp = db.Employees
           .Include(x => x.CostCenter)
           .Single(e => e.Id == 123);
```